# ANT doesn't run anything inside <target>

Tags: java, ant

When i put any thing inside a target tag its doesn't run whats inside it. eg.

```
<project name="Test" >
    <target name="clean">
        <delete dir="bin" />
        <mkdir dir="bin" />
        <echo>Hello 1</echo>
    </target>

    <target name="compile" depends="clean">
        <javac srcdir="src" destdir="bin" />
        <echo>Hello 2</echo>
    </target>

    <echo>Hello 3</echo>
</project>
```

All i get is:

[echo] Hello 3

Comment: Please provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Comment: You can set `verbose` property for more information and add `echo` tag call to your target to make sure that it was called

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could either set a default task like

```
<project name="Test" default="compile">
```

or invoke a task from command lie (or IDE)

```
ant compile
```

Answer (score 2):

Well no wonder since your project has no default = "" attribute specified.

You will either have to write the project element like this :

```
<project name="Test" default="compile">
```

Or you will have to call the ant.bat or whatever it is you are calling with the specified target to run.